# How to resolve a conflict between jQuery script and basic JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got some pages that I have developed using a jQuery script, which automatically displays suggested results for a text form, and also some JavaScript that I implemented to display an overlay and close it via an event listener.

The problem is, there is one spot on the page where the two scripts intersect: where there is a form element (using the jQuery script) inside a box being controlled by the JavaScript event listener.

No matter what I do, when the user clicks on the dropdown menu created by the jQuery, the overlay disappears. Because the event listener thinks you've clicked outside the overlay div, even though you haven't.

So, how do I fix this?  I've tried adding an `event.stopPropogation()` in the JavaScript to exempt the tags `div`, but that doesn't seem to work.  I've also tried adding an exception to the jQuery, but maybe I'm just not doing that correctly.

Here is the jQuery script:

```
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
    '.$tags1.'
            ];
    function split( val ) {
      return val.split( /,\s*/ );
    }
    function extractLast( term ) {
      return split( term ).pop();
    }

    $( "#tags" )
      .on( "keydown", function( event ) {
        if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
            $( this ).autocomplete( "instance" ).menu.active ) {
          event.preventDefault();
       }
  })
  .autocomplete({
            minLength: 0,
            source: function( request, response ) {
              // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
              response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
            },
            focus: function() {
              // prevent value inserted on focus
              return false;
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
              var terms = split( this.value );
              // remove the current input
              terms.pop();
              // add the selected item
              terms.push( ui.item.value );
              // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
              terms.push( "" );
              this.value = terms.join( ", " );
              return false;
            }
          });
        } );
```

And here is what I'm using for the JavaScript to place the overlay and allow clicks inside to not affect it.

```
window.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    var box = document.getElementById('menu');
    box.style.display = 'none';

    var box2 = document.getElementById('overlay22');
    box2.style.display = 'none';

});

var boxa = document.getElementById('establishmentmenu');
boxa.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});

var box = document.getElementById('menu');
box.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Any idea how I can stop the overlay layer from being hidden when I click in the jQuery menu?

**EDIT: Added code snippet in the compiler.  Unfortunately, it compiles but won't produce the overlay.  Not sure if I missed something, or if this isn't allowed for some reason.**

```js
 $(function() {
 var availableTags = [
 "#eastside", "#west6th", "#historic6th", "#austin"
   ];
 function split( val ) {
   return val.split( /,\s*/ );
 }
 function extractLast( term ) {
   return split( term ).pop();
 }

 $( "#tags" )
   .on( "keydown", function( event ) {
  if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
   $( this ).autocomplete( "instance" ).menu.active ) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  event.stopPropagation();
   })
   .autocomplete({
  minLength: 0,
  source: function( request, response ) {
    // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
    response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
   availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
  },
  focus: function() {
    // prevent value inserted on focus
    return false;
  },
  select: function( event, ui ) {
    var terms = split( this.value );
    // remove the current input
    terms.pop();
    // add the selected item
    terms.push( ui.item.value );
    // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
    terms.push( "" );
    this.value = terms.join( ", " );
    return false;
  }
   });
 } );
  
  window.addEventListener('click', function(event){
 
 var box2 = document.getElementById('overlay22');
 box2.style.display = 'none';
 
 var box5 = document.getElementById('tagsbox');
 box5.style.display = 'none';

});

var box5 = document.getElementById('tagsbox');
box5.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
 event.stopPropagation();
});

 function toggle(id){
  var myDiv=document.getElementById(id);
  if(myDiv.style.display=='none'||myDiv.style.display==''){
   myDiv.style.display='block';
  }
  else{closeD(id)}
 }
 
 function closeD(id){
  document.getElementById(id).style.display='none';
 }
```

```css
#overlay22 {
 display: none;
    width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
    position:fixed;
    z-index: 8;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.6);
    /*overflow-x: hidden;*/
}

.linkLike {
   cursor: pointer;
 color: rgb(65, 135, 175);
 text-decoration: none;
 transition: color 0.2s ease;
}

#tagsbox{
 display: none;
 width: 600px;
 height: 480px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 position: relative;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-top: 125px;
 padding-top: 4px;
 padding-left: 20px;
 padding-right: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 z-index: 10;
 color: white;
 background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.8);
 overflow-y: auto;
}

#overlaywrap {
    width: 100%;
 height: 0px;
    position:fixed;
    z-index: 8;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    /*overflow-x: hidden;*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<body>
<span class="linkLike" onClick="toggle('overlay22');toggle('tagsbox');">Suggest Tags</span>

<div id="overlay22"></div>
<div id="overlaywrap">
<div id="tagsbox"><h2>Add Tags: Jack & Ginger's</h2>
 <form id="tagsinfo" action="https://www.theaustinindustry.com/submissions/tagssubmit.php?action=012619" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
 <div id="tagsboxinner"><span class="reputationcomment">
 Users must have a reputation of at least 50 to propose tags be added to a venue!<br><br>Users must have a reputation of at least 500 to add without moderation or create new tags!</span><br>
 <br>
    <p><b>Location Tags: </b><br>#austin, #domain, #rockrose<br><input type="text" id="tags" name="locationtags" size="26" placeholder="Add Location Tags #tag1, #tag2"></p>
    <p><b>Description Tags: </b><br>#pub, #restaurant, #Irish, #tableservice, #coveredpatio, #bar<br><input type="text" id="tags2" name="descriptiontags" size="26" placeholder="Add Description Tags #tag1, #tag2"></p></div>
 <button id="submit4" type="submit4" name="submit4" value="submit4">Submit</button>
   <button type="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button>
 </form></div>
  </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: yeah, don't hide the overlay if the event target is the jquery menu or one of it's children.

Comment: But how would I implement that?  Would it be in the javascript or the jquery code.  Sorry if that should be obvious, but I don't work with jquery at all other than this.

Comment: it would be the same in either case. but i'd recommend doing it within the existing window click handler.

Comment: jQuery *is* JavaScript, guy.

Comment: It's a library written on javascript correct?  The syntax is completely different.  And you have to have the correct jquery library loaded to use those functions as well...right??

Comment: Right, but it's just javascript. It gives you a function, that does stuff. it's well documented.

Comment: @KevinB I think the problem I'm running into is that the ul for the dropdown menu is written on the fly.  So if I try to add it with an event handler it comes up as null and throws an error.  I'm kind of confused in general as to why the div the jquery is creating isn't considered a child of the div I'm already handling correctly.

Comment: it depends on how the jquery plugin is written. For all i know it could be appending it to the body. Use inspect element to find out.

Comment: It would be best if you could provide a [mcve] showing the problem occurring. Right now we're trying to use our imagination to figure out how your code is interacting with some mythical HTML, and my mental stack doesn't run that deep...

Comment: What's going on here? `}e({` Guessing it's a failed copy/paste of `$( this ).autocomplete`

Comment: @KevinB Sorry, that was a typo where I tried to remove one of my attempts  Accidentally removed 2 lines.  It is corrected in the original post now.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Should I post a link to a scaled down version of the page?  Or is there a way to use the javascript code on stack exchange to enter it all?

Comment: No, you should not post a link. You should break your code down until you have the least amount necessary to show the problem (as described in that help center article I linked to in my previous comment). Then you can use Stack Snippets to post the relevant HTML, JavaScript, and CSS. Click the icon that has `<>` in a page.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I did as you suggested, and I can't seem to get the simulation to run correctly, though it compiles fine. Just not my day I guess.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would suggest that you use a consistent method to attach event handlers. It usually just adds unnecessary confusion to use jquery and vanilla js for the same thing. Stick to either of those.

To tackle your problem, either of the following approaches should help you:

If elements are created on the fly, they do not trigger event handlers that have been attached *before* their creation. You can easily attach event handlers with jquery dynamically by changing

```
$('.yourelement').on('click', function(){});
```

to the following notation:

```
// It's usually encouraged to use the nearest ancestor element
// as reference point instead of 'body'
$('body').on('click', '.yourelement', function(){});
```

(In earlier jQuery versions this was done via a separate function called `live`.)
With this notation, any newly created element will be taken into account. Now stopping the propagation should work reliably even for newly created elements.

Also, an `event` also gives you the `target` property, which you can use to exclude certain elements if the above method does not work for you. Seen in the following pseudo code:

```
function(event){
    // here you could also check for a common parent instead of every child element
    if (event.target == "element you want to exclude"){
         return;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"It usually just adds unnecessary confusion to use jquery and vanilla js for the same thing. Stick to either of those."* unless... these are separate js files of course. then there's no confusion at all.

Comment: @KevinB does not matter. Even if you have separate files, you should stick to a consistent notation. Once you have a big enough project, you will understand.

Comment: Absolutely not, i wouldn't recommend using jquery in a react app to bind events just because you have jquery elsewhere on the page in another file.

Comment: In that case, You should consider not using jquery in the first place. Anyway -
 do you think this invalidates this answer enough to downvote it?

Comment: I don't see the answer as useful. `if (event.target == "element you want to exclude"){` gets you halfway there, but surely you wouldn't suggest doing that for each and every element within the dropdown popup. a better solution would be to detect children of a specific element.

Comment: I doubt that both the solutions I provided cannot solve OP's problem, but apparently you also would want to include two "overlapping" frameworks, so I'm not surprised you fail to see this :-) Is it too hard to imagine, that `"element you want to include"` is actually the parent element you need?

Comment: that wouldn't work though, the parent element wouldn't be the event target. you'd need a bit more logic than that.

Comment: You are aware, that `event.target` has parents as well? Once again I sadly realize, that SO has deteriorated to "give me the codez because I do not want to think"... :-(

Comment: @Christoph Thanks for the response.  The problem I have I think is that I have never taken the time to learn jquery.  And the first part of the code was given to me as a working script.  It may seem silly to you pros, but the syntax looks completely different if you don't have experience with it.  I prefer to focus on learning javascript.

Comment: @Keith it was by no means meant as an offense to you! I think it is a good move to focus on learning native javascript. However, JQuery has some interesting concepts you might want to look into. Also it makes writing standard code really easy, so it's totally fine to use it. Please try my suggestions and let me know, if you need further assistance!

Comment: @Christoph Appreciate the kind words.  I guess part of the basis of my confusion is: I'm not sure exactly which element I'm trying to stop the propogation for?  Would it be the div id=tags?  Or would it be the entire UL element it creates?  Or would I have to go all the way down to the individual list elements by id?  I'd prefer to handle in javascript at the end, but it seems like the safer way would be to edit the jquery script.